# How do I set/check the compression used in gRPC in c#

Tags: c#, compression, grpc

How do I check/configure/enable and disable compression in grpc in c#? Im following the examples at grpc.io homepage on how to use grpc in c# (https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/csharp). However, I cannot find any way of setting/getting the compression. The goal is to maximize transfer of large blobs of data (using streaming) locally.

Im very new to grpc and perhaps my question is trivial but have not been able to find the answer. There seem to be a way to automatically create a service project in c# where one can set compression. However, a service does not suit my need since the grpc server is intended to live inside a desktop app.

Comment: Does [this post from 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031763/grpc-compression-in-c-sharp) answer your question?

Comment: I think that your question is not specific to gRPC, but to the underlying HTTP/2 connection. IMHO it is possible to configure the HTTP/2 connection to use compression. Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-5.0 , maybe it helps.

Comment: The old post didnt help much. The author said he could configure the channel on the server side with ChannelOptions. But I can only do that on the client side, and it had no effect. Im only testing download from the server so maybe it only affects the upload. I could also add             
var headers = new Metadata { new Metadata.Entry("grpc-internal-encoding-request", "gzip") };
await context.WriteResponseHeadersAsync(headers);
That made it really slow as mentioned in the post from 2018. Maybe that is the effect of compression.

Comment: Xavier, Im not sure how to configure that since Im not making an ASP.NET app.

Comment: I found how to set the compression on the server side. Now it seem to work. Although it is very slow when compression is activated. So I should definately not use that. Another issue showed up though. When using streaming both the server and client side consume a huge amount of memory. Seems like both sides buffer the entire message. So by sending 1.5GB both client and server side end up using 3GB. But that will be another question soon if I cannot figure it out.

Comment: @AndersG can you publish the way to the compression on server side?