# gRPC C# - How do disable compression or caching completely?

Tags: c#, grpc

I have a gRPC channel where both the client and server are implemented in C#.

I want to test the network delay it takes to send maximum size messages (4MB) from the client to the server, and I get very inconsistent results.

I want to disable any optimization gRPC has on the channel - compression, caching, etc. to get the "delay" and then compare it to the optimized delay.

There are excerpts of solutions of how to enable compression spread in several [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031763/grpc-compression-in-c-sharp) but it isn't clear how to disable compression in both client and server side, or how to disable other channel optimizations.

How do I disable any channel optimization in C# code?

Comment: Why not generate random data as the message payload? That should effectively defeat compression and caching.

Comment: Thought about that, I still get weird behaviors (messages sent in much shorter time than expected) so I want to make sure it's not any gRPC optimization

Comment: I would suggest using some profiler to verify that the time is spent sending the gRPC messages, and not something completely unrelated. A common issue is that the first time something is done it might need to be initialized, taking some extra time.